# Chrome Latest Update dropdown fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, google-chrome

does anyone notice on chrome 83 latest the form input element, well, the dropdown (option) inside a select element is oddly looking? See my image below. Chrome Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build).

[image: Weird dropdown truncated on Chrome Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build)]

I'm not putting any css for the option. But I add a select style for that dropdown which is this:

```
select {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 padding: 0 .6em;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

When opened on Edge and Firefox, the dropdown looks just fine, it was fine before updating the chrome browser. But now since the browser got this black bold border on select option, it looks like the option itself having some padding on each side and on it's bottom but not on the top one.

```
<select name="input_1" id="input_3_1" class="medium field_select" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
 <option value="" selected="selected" class="field_placeholder">My Enquiry</option>
 <option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
 <option value="Price Information">Price Information</option>
 <option value="Scheduling an information">Scheduling an information</option>
 <option value="Rates &amp; Fees">Rates &amp; Fees</option>
 <option value="Similar Properties">Similar Properties</option>
</select>
```

I've tried to add outline: none !important but that doesn't work. it's already using box-sizing: border-box;

The only way around was using custom select via js, but that's gonna take more time to restyling so I bet the best one that I can do is just using browser's built-in form elements.

Please help,
Thanks!

---

in case the image is not clear: https://pasteboard.co/JdL8cnx.png

> > updated the select structure

Comment: Is it not an issue with your padding and line height? Can you add a snippet to your question?

Comment: Provide your html code please for us too look further or an example of your code.

Comment: @learningtoanimate I put padding and line-height on select only, when I remove or commenting it, the option just looks the same (still oddly looking)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I put the select structure there as the form part is built on gravity form but with no styling on it. Gravity form is from wordpress. For note, on different form, without generating from gform, the select and option looks oddly still. So gform is not the issue as I suspect.

Comment: @Hernanda i would you remove the line height to see if that fixes the issue. Let me know.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping already done that, still it's not changing anything. Even when I use line-height 1, line-height normal, unset it, or just commenting it. On browser inspect, there is no style applied to it other than those snippet on my post.

Comment: @Hernanda Can you share link to web if you need more help here. Thanks